# sms delivery in sms receiver not working

Tags: android, sms

I want to handle sms delivery even if my app stopped or phone restarted! so I think I have to implement something similar to what smsReceiver does, so I definded an smsReceiver in manifest like this:

theses are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

this is my receiver definition in manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and finally this is my reveiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

  @Override
  public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
  {
      Toast.makeText(context, "SmsReceived or Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } 
}
```

This toast displayed just when an sms received, not when an sms delivered.

any body can help?

Comment: post your complete `code`

Comment: this is my complete code yet,I will complete my code after I get success to displaying toast for both status (receiving sms and sms delivery)

Comment: i use complement code , i post answer , dadash

Comment: do you send sms in your app , or user send sms ?

Comment: yes I send sms in my app, but I don't like to register a broadcastReceiver for delivery in the same class I send sms, because it is unreliable. for example if my app closed it will not work, so I want to implement something like  BroadcastReceiver for incoming SMS.